# How does ActiveMQ distribute messages among consumers?

Tags: queue, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ.

The problem arises that we have a request queue where we leave a message for the consumer to perform a process and then return the response in a response queue in which the producers are subscribed.
It works fine, but now there is a second producer that sends a message for the same consumer to perform the operation and return the response in the response queue.

As ActiveMQ determines which of the consumers of the response queue corresponds to the response of the process. Here is a graph for better detail:
[image]

Comment: It looks like you are asking: How to determine which response relates which request as a common queue is being used by both producers?

Comment: @Shashi yes exactly, if the job is done automatically by the broker or some extra configuration must be done

Comment: In order to do request/response reliably you either need to use a correlation ID to match the request & response together or you need to use temporary queues. Both of these patterns are well-documented in the industry. A quick search should provided more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a request/response messaging pattern, a CorrelationId is used to relate request and response. For example if producer A puts a request with message Id 1000. The consumer processes that request and sends a response message with CorrelationId set to message id (1000 in this example) of the request message. Then the producer sets a filter condition "give me message from response queue where respnseMessage.CorrelationId=requestMessage.messageId" when it wants to get the response message. This is how requests/responses are correlated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, an additional query, I have to add that filter condition in each producer that listens or is there a way to do it globally in the broker, I currently use ActiveMQ

Comment: The consumer has to set the selector as it is the only entity that knows the correlation ID that it sets on the request message. The broker can't do this for you.